# I dropped my Nikon 18-55 lens — can I fix it?

Tags: nikon, repair, equipment-damage, kit-lens

The camera fell on the floor and now I can't turn it to 18mm, its stuck on 55mm and only moves 1/2 inch when I try to turn it. Anyway I can fix it?

Comment: Also many other related questions available that answer this, but the one suggested as duplicate I think covers the most important parts.

Comment: How is "Is it worth paying to have it repaired" and "Can I fix it myself" the same question?

Comment: @MichaelClark "no user servicable parts inside".

Comment: @jwenting That depends on the user. See   http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/05/a-few-easy-lens-dustings

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. Lens repair is usually fairly complex and requires specialized tools and expertise. If you had the expertise and tools to fix it you probably wouldn't be asking the question here. The minimum charge to have a reputable repair shop or factory service even look at it is probably significantly more than the price for which you could find a good used copy.